# React Native: How to separate roles of developer and 'styler'

Tags: react-native, styles

I'm working on a React Native app (initially only Web) where we need to separate the roles of developer and styler (i.e. the person responsible for styling the app). With traditional HTML development this is easily done through CSS. In other words, the developer assigns IDs and/or classes to HTML elements, allowing the CSS developer to get to work on the CSS files of the code-base.

Is it possible to do something similar in React Native? In other words, can we change the styles of the various elements of the user interface without needing to modify the code that generates the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I think the `style` property of view is pretty similar to CSS, you just need to write a  `styles.js` file separate from your view code. Then your "styler" just need to modify style attributes in that file instead of go into the main code.

Something like this:

Your styles.js

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
       flexDirection: 'column',
       backgroundColor: Colors.COLOR_BACKGROUND_LIGHT,
       paddingBottom: normalize(50)
   },
   buttonContainer: {
       flexDirection: 'column',
       alignItems: 'center',
       padding: Dimens.contentPadding
   },
   inputContainer: {
       flexDirection: 'row',
       height: normalize(30),
       borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
       alignItems: 'center',
       borderBottomColor: Colors.COLOR_LIGHT_GREY,
   },
});
```

Your index.js

```
import styles from ".....";
.....
.....
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            ...
        </View>
    )
}
```

Hope that help ^^

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! This approach looks promising.

Does it allow us to target specific elements or only classes of elements? For example, say a form has three buttons, can we target styles at just the third one and not the other two? With CSS you could either define a class for the third button or give the third one an ID. Could we do something similar in React Native?

Comment: Yes of course @HansA. You just need to define a different style for third button in your styles.js and then use it in your third button component style. --> It will be different from the others ^^